# Testing @ConfigurationProperties annotation without loading Spring context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I'm trying to test a class that has the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation but without loading the entire Spring context. I tried using only the JUnit5's features in order to do that but until now didn't succeed in that.

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-parent` v2.6.2 .

The class I'm testing :

```
@ConfigurationProperties("db.mongo")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class MongoProperties {
    private String host;
    private String db;
    private String user;
    private String password;
}
```

The application.yaml :

```
db:
  mongo:
    host: localhost
    db: test
    user: test-user
    password: secret
```

My Test class :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({MongoProperties.class})
public class MongoPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private  MongoProperties properties;

    @Test
    public void mongoPropertiesLoadedTest(){
        assertNotNull(properties.getDb());
        assertNotNull(properties.getHost());
        assertNotNull(properties.getPassword());
        assertNotNull(properties.getUser());
    }
}
```

The `MongoProperties` bean is injected successfully, but all the values inside are null and the asserts fail.

Adding the `@SpringBootTest` solves the issue of the null values in the instance of the bean, but it also starts the whole spring context which is what I don't want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

But using `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` will also start the spring context. The difference is that it starts the context in a traditional way but `@SpringBootTest` starts it in a spring-boot way. So no matter you use which of them , it still requires to start the spring context.

If your concern is to minimise the number of beans required to be loaded into the spring context when using `@SpringBootTest`, you can actually configure a specified `@Configuration` like the following as by default `@SpringBootTest` will load all beans defined in your applications which may be too much for testing (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.detecting-configuration) for details) :

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class MongoPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private  MongoProperties properties;

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({MongoProperties.class})
    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

If you really want to just use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` , you will lose the spring-boot feature such as [externalising configuration features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) which cause you cannot load properties from `application.properties` and cannot support loading properties from `YAML` file etc. You have to manually configure `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer` to enable such features :

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class MongoPropertiesTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties properties;

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({MongoProperties.class})
    public static class Config {

    }

}
```

You can consider to further use `@SpringJUnitConfig` to combine `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration` together which gives you :

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class MongoPropertiesTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private MongoProperties properties;

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({MongoProperties.class})
    public static class Config {

    }
}
```

Actually both approaches do not have much differences in term of speed , so I prefer to just use `@SpringBootTest` for simplicity as it does not requires you to configure `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer`.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that the context that is loaded via @ExtendWidth(SpringExtension.class) isnt supporting loading properties from the application yaml  right ? The alternative is using @SpringBootTest with a specific context (in order to minimize the amount of beans created)

Comment: Yes. You summary the main points that I want to say. In the end no matter what you use , it still require to load the spring context , but you can minimize the amount of beans created in both cases by a specific context which your test should still run very fast

Comment: Got it. So the ExtendWith(SpringExtension) supports only a small amount of spring features because it minimizes the amount of beans it loads in the background ? I know the @Autowired and InjectMocks annotations are working with this extension. Is there some kind of list that shows what spring features supported with this extension ?

Comment: `ExtendWith(SpringExtension)` simply does not know spring-boot , it is a spring-test framework stuff , and `@ SpringBootTest` build on top of the spring-test framework.  So all the spring-boot related features will not supported by `ExtendWith(SpringExtension)` by default , and you have to somehow to see if that feature can be enabled manually.  `@InjectMocks` is nothing to do with spring , it is a Mockito feature

Comment: I think saying that it does not know spring-boot is not that accurate. SpringExtension was build in order to assist testing some spring-based code with JUnit (correct me if you think I'm wrong). Therefore, you can see some useful annotation that can help you handle spring-based code like Autowired and MockBean that are supported by this extension. When you use SpringExtension you actually start a TestContext which suppose to be very slim.. Either way, Thank you for the clear explanations and for you quick assistance !

Comment: using @SpringBootTest(classes={MongoProperties.class}) will also load the test context only with the MongoProperties bean, right ?

Comment: @SpringJUnitConfig(initializers = ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class) solved for me, I could finally load config from property files. Thank you so much for this answer!!!